# jQuery ajax request can do XHR finished GET but not authorized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

> ```
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>
>             $.ajax({
>                 type: "GET",
>                 dataType: "json",
>                 contentType: "text/plain",
>                 xhrFields: {
>                     withCredentials: true
>                 },
>                 url: 'http://kitabisa.xyz/api/v2/campaigns',
>                 username: 'apps1',
>                 password: 'XD6WVjhcq3JVrFRldrpjEpAyUXg5LFzS9cmiGuXL3TmE7bkLGR',
>                 success: function(result) {
>                     alert('done');
>                 },
>                 complete: 'callback'
>             })
>         });
> ```

I want to GET JSON from API via jquery Ajax function, above is my code snippet, but the CORS Policy block the ajax, here is the console message.

[image]

```
I've tried the another method, I use beforeSend ajax here :


$(document).ready(function() {              
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     dataType: "jsonp",
                     contentType: "text/plain",
                     xhrFields: {
                         withCredentials: true
                     },
                     url: 'http://kitabisa.xyz/api/v2/campaigns',
                     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                         xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YXBwczE6WEQ2V1ZqaGNxM0pWckZSbGRycGpFcEF5VVhnNUxGelM5Y21pR3VYTDNUbUU3YmtMR1I=")
                     },
                     username: 'apps1',
                     password: 'XD6WVjhcq3JVrFRldrpjEpAyUXg5LFzS9cmiGuXL3TmE7bkLGR',
                     success: function(result) {
                         alert('done');
                     }
                 })
             });
```

But still not works.

Any suggestion to fix this problem? Thank you

Comment: We can't tell what conditions the server you are making the request to decides to return a 401 Not Authorized error.

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp"` — You can't set custom header fields or xhrFields unless you are using XHR

Comment: `contentType: "text/plain",` — You are making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content-type of.

Comment: Are you really posting credentials here?

Comment: "but the CORS Policy block the ajax" — That's the server saying you are Not Authorised. It has nothing to do with CORS / The Same Origin Policy.

Comment: `complete: 'callback'` — The value of `complete` needs to be a function, not a string.

Comment: A.Wolff : it just credential for testing purpose only, the JSON only contain public information

Quentin : any suggestion on server configuration to do ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "text/plain",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true,
                username: 'apps1',
            password: 'XD6WVjhcq3JVrFRldrpjEpAyUXg5LFzS9cmiGuXL3TmE7bkLGR'
            },
            url: 'http://kitabisa.xyz/api/v2/campaigns',
            success: function(result) {
                alert('done');
            },

        });
```

Comment: still not work bro, here's my header setting on server
http://pastebin.com/ydcHbuB8, any suggestion

Comment: i have droped this code in a jsfiddle and the authentification worked becouse it give me a CORS error that i need to be on domain http://design.kitabisa.xyz